# Windows 10 v10.0.18363.1016 - Cannot search using Win+S or using search in Explorer (top right bar) - Event Name: MoAppCrash

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana

Cannot use Windows search anymore.  I've checked and don't see any recent updates to my laptop.  When clicking in the box in upper right corner of Windows Explorer my PC briefly locks up, and a crash event is triggered.  Process Monitor will also show WerFault.exe running.  Same thing if pushing Windows Key + S.

Things I've tried:

- Rebuilding Index
- Troubleshooting Index (no issues found)
- SFC /scannow and DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
- Enabling allowsxs to allow legacy edge
- Disabling Cortana and re-enabling using these steps:

> 1. Disable and re-enable the search feature using CMD:
>
> dism /Online /Disable-Feature
> /FeatureName:"SearchEngine-Client-Package" (after you disable it you
> need to restart windows).
>
> dism /Online /Enable-Feature
> /FeatureName:"SearchEngine-Client-Package"
>
> 2. Reinstall Cortana Search App from Powershell
>
> a. Press WIN+X keys together to launch WIN+X menu and then click on
> Command Prompt (Admin) option. It'll open Command Prompt as
> Administrator.
>
> b. Now type Powershell in Command Prompt window and press Enter. Wait
> for a few moments and Powershell session will be initiated in Command
> Prompt window.
>
> c. Now type following command and press Enter:
>
> Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | foreach
> {Add-AppxPackage -register "$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml"
> -DisableDevelopmentMode}
>
> 3. Now open configuration > Cortana and select permissions from the left list. Now activate Cortana and what it can do. After doing this,
>    my search worked again.

Events:

```
Fault bucket 1227156440516620908, type 5 Event Name: MoAppCrash
Response: Not available Cab Id: 0

Problem signature: P1:
Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.13.0.18362_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
P2: praid:CortanaUI P3: 10.0.18362.997 P4: 5f112369 P5: edgehtml.dll
P6: 11.0.18362.1016 P7: b870b7e9 P8: 8000ffff P9: 000000000078f330
P10:
```

---

```
Faulting application name: SearchUI.exe, version: 10.0.18362.997, time stamp: 0x5f112369
Faulting module name: edgehtml.dll, version: 11.0.18362.1016, time stamp: 0xb870b7e9
Exception code: 0x8000ffff
Fault offset: 0x000000000078f330
Faulting process id: 0x35c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6883fb22fbcd5
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\edgehtml.dll
Report Id: 9e390814-980d-44df-9bb9-1bc10ef8c207
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.13.0.18362_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: CortanaUI
```

---

Dump Analysis

```
0:019> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

GetPageUrlData2 failed, server returned HTTP status 502
URL requested: http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/SearchUI.exe/10.0.18362.997/5f112369/edgehtml.dll/11.0.18362.1016/b870b7e9/8000ffff/0078f330.htm?Retriage=1
GetUrlPageData2 (WinHttp) failed: 31.

DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=00000052194fee20 rbx=00000052194ff350 rcx=00000052194fee20
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=00000052194fee20
rip=00007ff987e7f07f rsp=00000052194fed40 rbp=00000052194ff4b9
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000010040
r11=0000000000100000 r12=0000000000000001 r13=0000000000000060
r14=000001c0f1810228 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000244
KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0xaf:
00007ff9`87e7f07f 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
edgehtml!CDoc::Init+2b3ef0
00007ff9`16e8f330 cc              int     3

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ff916e8f330 (edgehtml!CDoc::Init+0x00000000002b3ef0)
   ExceptionCode: 8000ffff
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 0

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  SearchUI.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x8000ffff - Catastrophic failure

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x8000ffff (2147549183) - Catastrophic failure

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  8000ffff

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  5f112369

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  10.0.18362.997

PROCESS_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  edgehtml.dll

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  b870b7e9

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  78f330

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  11.0.18362.1016

MODULE_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft Edge Web Platform

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.18362.959 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH:  60330dfefd5d0f0be553ac78c9d6519541b83ad2

MODLIST_SHA1_HASH:  3f1279548e67e83550d1bdfc01a9bb2b0223dff7

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

DUMP_FLAGS:  94

DUMP_TYPE:  1

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  xxx

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  09-11-2020 08:56:23.0506

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
OS_LOCALE:  ENU

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00007ff916ec2a39 to 00007ff987e7f07f

STACK_TEXT:  
00000052`194fed40 00007ff9`16ec2a39 : 00007ff9`16e8f330 000001c0`f1818000 00007ff9`16e8f330 000001c0`f1818000 : KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0xaf
00000052`194ff310 00007ff9`16ec2a86 : 00000000`00000000 000001c0`f1a20020 000001c0`f1818000 00000052`194ff4b9 : edgehtml!Abandonment::InduceAbandonment+0xdd
00000052`194ff410 00007ff9`16e8f330 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000018 00000052`194ff528 00000052`194ff4b9 : edgehtml!Abandonment::InduceHRESULTAbandonment+0x26
00000052`194ff440 00007ff9`16c491f1 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 000001c0`f1a20020 00000000`00000000 : edgehtml!CDoc::Init+0x2b3ef0
00000052`194ff520 00007ff9`16a76141 : 00000000`00000000 00000052`194ff600 00007ff9`17baa090 000001c0`f1810228 : edgehtml!CBaseCF::CreateInstance+0xa1
00000052`194ff560 00007ff9`16a7640c : 00007ff9`17dcd4e8 000001c0`f1810000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : edgehtml!InternalCreateInstance+0xc1
00000052`194ff5a0 00007ff9`16a76335 : 000001c0`f1810048 00000052`194ff710 000001c0`f1810048 00007ff9`00000000 : edgehtml!CWebPlatformTridentHost::_OnSetClientSite+0xc8
00000052`194ff640 00007ff9`16a75be0 : 000001b8`f144c800 000001b8`f144c960 000001b8`f0124360 00000000`00000000 : edgehtml!CWebPlatformTridentHost::SetClientSite+0x25
00000052`194ff670 00007ff9`16a75ad5 : 000001b8`f144c800 000001b8`f144c800 00000000`00000000 00000052`194ff970 : edgehtml!CWebPlatform::_OnInPlaceActivate+0xb0
00000052`194ff740 00007ff9`16a3f3e7 : 000001b8`f14657f0 00000052`194ff889 00000052`194ff970 00000000`003115d2 : edgehtml!CWebPlatform::_OnActivateChange+0x95
00000052`194ff770 00007ff9`16a3fd8f : 000001b8`f1465850 00000052`194ff970 000001b8`f1465850 00000000`00000243 : edgehtml!CCoreWebViewTaskHandler::_OleActivateWebPlatform+0x9b
00000052`194ff7c0 00007ff9`16bca373 : 000001b8`f143f440 000001b8`f14575e0 00000052`183fc480 00007ff9`00000001 : edgehtml!CCoreWebViewTaskHandler::Initialize+0x31f
00000052`194ff8d0 00007ff9`16bca171 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 000001b8`f14575c0 : edgehtml!CCoreWebViewDispatcher::ThreadProcInitialize+0x15b
00000052`194ffa70 00007ff9`8a557bd4 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : edgehtml!_DocumentThreadProc+0x61
00000052`194ffaa0 00007ff9`8aa2ce51 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
00000052`194ffad0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  4bb5353777e1814e0d31f78f82499fda11e0e8e9

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  21294b49fed2471656e5be9933f8034702d41a4a

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  5acdbe17edf94c7fb9e41ac160b8783b3c62983b

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
edgehtml!CDoc::Init+2b3ef0
00007ff9`16e8f330 cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  c78b49cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  edgehtml!CDoc::Init+2b3ef0

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: edgehtml

IMAGE_NAME:  edgehtml.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

STACK_COMMAND:  .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_edgehtml!CDoc::Init+2b3ef0

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT_edgehtml!CDoc::Init+2b3ef0

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  8000ffff

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  edgehtml.dll

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  edgehtml.dll

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  edgehtml

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  edgehtml

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  CDoc::Init

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  CDoc::Init

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  2b3ef0

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  0

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  18bdb05

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  11.0.18362.1016

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  edgehtml.dll!CDoc::Init

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_8000ffff_edgehtml.dll!CDoc::Init

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/SearchUI.exe/10.0.18362.997/5f112369/edgehtml.dll/11.0.18362.1016/b870b7e9/8000ffff/0078f330.htm?Retriage=1

TARGET_TIME:  2020-09-11T13:48:33.000Z

OSBUILD:  18363

OSSERVICEPACK:  959

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  256

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt SingleUserTS

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  unknown_date

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160101.0800

BUILDLAB_STR:  WinBuild

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.18362.959

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 4674

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:application_fault_8000ffff_edgehtml.dll!cdoc::init

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {469472d8-8601-611a-23cb-ed12c65dc0fe}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Comment: Did you happen to remove Edge from your system?  The faulting module is directly linked to Legacy Edge.  Did you recently install Chromium Edge through Windows Update by chance?

Comment: No, I have Edge and actually use it on occassion. I'm running version 85.0.564.51 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: I am asking if you removed Legacy Edge.  Edge 85.0.564.51 doesn't use `EdgeHTML.dll` at all

Comment: So you system is 4 weeks out of date.  This problem might be fixed by installing the current cumlative patch (KB4574727) but it might take either upgrading to 2004 or performing an in-place upgrade of 1903 to resolve you problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, sorry I missed the word "Legacy".  I haven't removed legacy Edge, but also I don't have allowsxs for legacy Edge enabled.

Comment: Did Chromium Edge get installed manually or by the appropriate patch through Windows Update?  It's weird some of the build versions, actually indicate your system has not been updated since July, but other versions indicated the beginning of August.

Comment: Okay, I enabled the Allowsxs key, reinstalled Edge.  I can access Edge legacy and normal Edge now, both launch fine.  Search is still broken.

Comment: @Ramhound, not sure.  Windows Updates are handled by policy on my laptop.

Comment: You will need to contact your IT Administrator in that case.  The commands you issue assumed that Cortana wasn't actually crashing.

Comment: I figured this out... Running Process Monitor on the SearchUI.exe I found it was faulting right after trying to read HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Internet Settings\Zones.  I viewed the permissions for the key and they looked fine, my account had full access as did SYSTEM and the Administrators group.  Poking around in other keys I saw 'ALL APPPLICATION PACKAGES' had read permission on a few of them.  I added the 'ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES' group with READ permission and the issue was resolved.